# calender object in android

Tags: java

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
 Intent intent = new Intent(Login_activity.this, EnqueryNotification_Service.class);
 PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Login_activity.this, 0, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 36000 * 1000, pintent);
```

what is this `cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);` **10 stands for?**

Comment: The amount to add to the field.

Comment: This is not really an android specific question. Calendar is a Java api.

Answer (score 2):

`cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);` adds 10 seconds to the current Calendar instance.

Answer (score 0):

With this function you are adding 10 seconds to this calendar object. You should have a look at the Calendar API [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Cheers